# PHP get current latitude longitude and pass as string to query phpmyadmin database

Tags: php

I'm trying to query my database according to current geolocation.
I have tried to find examples because this is all new to me.
When I execute this code with the hardcoded values (45.344779 and -73.740337), it gives me the result I expect. I would like to pass the person's current geolocation Latitude and Longitude as string to do the query but it's not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Current Latitude & Longitude</title>
<script>
if(!navigator.geolocation){
    alert('Your Browser does not support HTML5 Geo Location. Please Use       Newer Version Browsers');
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
function success(position){
var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;   
var longitude = position.coords.longitude;  
}
function error(err){
alert('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
}
</script>
<body>

<?php
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = 'xxxxxx';
$userdb = 'xxxxxx';
$passdb = 'xxxxxx';

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8

$sql="SELECT *,
SQRT(POW((69.1 * (MyTable.Latitude - :Latitude)) , 2 ) + 
POW((53 * (MyTable.Longitude - :Longitude)), 2)) AS distance 
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY distance ASC 
LIMIT 3";

$sqlprep = $conn->prepare($sql);       

$ar_val = array('Latitude'=> 45.344779, 'Longitude'=> -73.740337);

if($sqlprep->execute($ar_val)) {
// gets and displays the data returned by MySQL
while($row = $sqlprep->fetch()) echo $row['Direction'].' - '.$row['Km'].' : '.$row['Latitude'].' & '.$row['Longitude'].'<br />';
}
  $conn = null;        
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  }
  ?>
```

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What your trying to do, if I understand correctly, is getting the current position of the client and display your table content ordered by the distance...
To do that, you need to pass the javascript variable to php. You can not do that in the same page, you need to refresh the current page and pass the coordinates via get or post, or call the separate php part page via ajax.
You could also do it entirely on php side, by gathering the coordinates from the ip of the client and using the a service like http://ipinfo.io/, but this has some limits.

Comment: Thank You Franz for the information and for your time. I will try to do it using Javascript as suggested to change the query for something like: $ar_val = array('Latitude'=> UserLat, 'Longitude'=> UserLon);